# What is the difference between scope and entity in hapijs?

Tags: hapi.js

I'm looking at some of the auth config options for hapi routes. I understand how scope works - you can set the scope of a route to `'admin'` which means the user's credentials must have a scope that matches...but what is the purpose of `entity`?

Here are the docs:

- **entity** - the required authenticated entity type. If set, must match
  the entity value of the authentication credentials. Available values:

  - **any** - the authentication can be on behalf of a user or application. This is the default value.
  - **user** - the authentication must be on behalf of a user.
  - **app** - the authentication must be on behalf of an application.

When I set entity to `'user'` on a route I get this error:

`"message": "Application credentials cannot be used on a user endpoint"`

Which leads me to believe my auth plugin is setting my entity somewhere to `'app'`? For reference I am using [hapi-auth-jwt](https://github.com/ryanfitz/hapi-auth-jwt).

Comment: Could you post the plugin code?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old post, in case this can help others, the answer to this is that the *authentication is considered to be on behalf of an end-user* if the *credentials* object contains a property *user*.

In your case, if the *credentials* object didn't contain such a *user* property, this was considered as an *authentication on behalf of an application*, hence the access control failure. Your `auth.access.entity` definition made your endpoint a *user endpoint* but your credentials where not considered as user credentials but *application credentials*.

If your credentials object contains the identity of the user in another property (e.g. *sub* or *email*), you may want to copy it into a new property *user* in your authentication plugin or as part of the validation function you are using to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell `hapi-auth-jwt` what entity the authenticated request has in your validator function:

```
var validate = function (decodedToken, callback) {
  ...

  credentials = {
    entity: 'user',
    ...
  };

  return callback(error, authorized, credentials)
};
```

More about the credentials object [here](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/auth).